# segmentation fault in a linked list while loop?

Tags: c

I'm trying to setup a graph in C. I tried the graph with user input and it works perfectly. However, i am trying to implement a read from file. The last else statement is where the error is coming from because when i commented it out it compiles without any problems. I have included a comment over the block i think that has the problem. Please let me know if there is anything else needed for this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

//int counter and mainVertex would be used to determine if graph is connected.

// void graphConnection(){
// 
// 
// 
// 
// 
// 
// }


char* deblank(char* input)
{
    int i,j;
    char *output=input;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i<strlen(input); i++,j++)
    {
        if (input[i]!=' ')
            output[j]=input[i];
        else
            j--;
    }
    output[j]=0;
    return output;
}


struct node *G[1000];
int counter = 0;
char *mainVertex;

void readingEachLine(){

  FILE * fp;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

  //Read file and exit if fail
  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    line = deblank(line);
    int i = 0;
    struct node* cursor = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* secondcursor = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* tempitem;
    while(line[i] != '\n'){

      //If its the first of the line look into the array and set struct cursor to the corresponding
      //array position

      if (i == 0){
        mainVertex[counter] = line[0];
        int convertor = line[i] - '0';
        cursor = G[convertor];
        counter++;
      }
      //if its not the first, then set a struct with that number as data

      else{
        tempitem = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        int convertor = line[i] - '0';
        tempitem->data = convertor;
        tempitem->next = NULL;
      }
      //if there is no element connected to the struct in array, connect the tempitem

      if (cursor->next == NULL){
        cursor->next = tempitem;
      }
      //If there are already connected elements, loop until the end of the linked list
      //and append the tempitem
      //ERROR: I GET SEGMENTATION FAULT FROM HERE. TRIED AFTER COMMENTING IT OUT

      else{
        secondcursor = cursor;
        while(secondcursor->next != NULL){
          secondcursor = secondcursor->next;
        }
        secondcursor->next = tempitem;
      }
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(void){
  for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
  {
      G[i]= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      G[i]->data = i;
      G[i]->next = NULL;
  }
  readingEachLine();
}
```

EDIT: This is how the text file looks like:

```
1 3 4
2 4
3 1 4
4 2 1 3
```

Comment: OT:  regarding: `if (fp == NULL)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`  This results in the program exiting without giving the user any indication of what happened.  Suggest: `if (fp == NULL) {  perror( "fopen failed" );  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` as the call to `perror()` will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.,

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was success

Comment: Is it possible to post these in an answer? Very good advise and would like the explanation

Comment: code should be written to be as robust and is reasonable. code should be written to be very friendly to the user.   These 'OT' comments are NOT an answer to your question, and are not mandatory to the execution of the code, so they are given the prefix 'OT'  (offtopic)

Comment: regarding: int convertor = line[i] - '0';  The code should be checking that the first character is a digit (0....9) before trying to convert the first character to a `int`

Comment: For OT part sorry didnt understand it. For int part, the characters in file are always numbers. That would count as user error and im not checking for that now. Trying to figure out the basic problems first.

Comment: regarding: `while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) `  the function: `getline()` can resulting in reusing the same pointer from `line`, so before calling the function, each time including the first time, `line` should be set to NULL and `len` should be set to 0

Comment: regardless of what the input file is expected to contain, the code should always verify rather than making any assumptions

Comment: the posted code is calling `malloc()` MANY times, but fails to call `free()` for each of those allocated memory pointers, before exiting the program.  The result is the program is expecting the OS to clean up after the program.  The code should never expect the OS to perform cleanup functions that the program should have done.  Similar considerations exist for the open file that the program should have called `fclose()` to close the file before exiting

Comment: regarding the `deblank()` function, once any blank is encountered, every following loop must move the char at input[i] to output[j].   The loop is failing to do this when the current character at input[i] is not a blank.

Comment: if the input file contains more than 9 lines, then the line counter will be 2 or more characters, but the code is not allowing for this

Comment: The cursors are pointers to already existing nodes, so don't allocate anything for them. The segmentation fault occurs when you set `mainVertex[counter] = line[0]`, because `mainVertex` is not pointing anywhere. What are the 1,000 pointers in `G` for?

Comment: OT: when initializing an array, and (on purpose) do not initialize the first entry in the array, it is best to place a comment with that fact, so those reading your code are no mislead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several misconceoptions:

- Apparently, you can have a maximum of 1,000 nodes. You have an array `G` of 1,000 head pointers to linked lists. Don't allocate memory for all 1,000 nodes at the beginning. At the beginning, all lists are empty and an empty linked list is one that has no node and whose head is `NULL`.
- In your example, `cursor` is used to iterate oer already existing pointers, so don't allocate memory for it. If you have code like this:

  ```
  struct node *p = malloc(...);

  // next use of p:
  p = other_node;
  ```

  you shouldn't allocate. You would overwrite `p` and lose the handle to the allocated memory. Not all pointers have to be initialised with `malloc`; allocate only if you *create* a node.
- Your idea to strip all spaces from a line and then parse single digits will fail if you ever have more then 9 nodes. (But you cater for 1,000 node.) Don't try to parse the numbers yourself. There are library functions for that, for example `strtol`.
- It is not clear what `mainVertex` is supposed to be. You use it only once, when you assign to it. You treat it like an array, but it is a global pointer, initialised to `NULL`. When you dereference it, you get undefined behaviour, which is where your segmentation fault probably comes from.

Here's a program that does what you want to do. (It always inserts nodes at the head for simplicity and it should have more allocation checks.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {
    maxNodes = 1000
};

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node *G[maxNodes];
size_t nnode = 0;

int read_graph(const char *fn)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    fp = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;

    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) {
        char *p;
        char *end;
        int id;
        int n;

        id = strtol(line, &end, 10);
        if (end == line) continue;

        if (id < 1 || id > maxNodes) break;

        if (id > nnode) nnode = id;
        id--;

        p = end;
        n = strtol(p, &end, 10);

        while (p != end) {
            struct node *nnew = malloc(sizeof(*nnew));

            nnew->data = n - 1;
            nnew->next = G[id];
            G[id] = nnew;

            p = end;
            n = strtol(p, &end, 10);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(line);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    if (read_graph("test.txt") < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't gread raph.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nnode; i++) {
        struct node *p = G[i];

        if (p) {
            printf("%d:", i + 1);

            for (; p; p = p->next) {
                printf(" %d", p->data + 1);
            }

            puts("");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nnode; i++) {
        struct node *p = G[i];

        while (p) {
            struct node *old = p;

            p = p->next;
            free(old);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```